# Git won't sync local repository with remote one

Tags: git, github

I use GitHub to maintain my projects. I have a problem with one of my repositories. It contains one file:

```
public function download($download_path, $download_file) {
    file_put_contents($download_path, $download_file);
}
```

The local one looks like:

```
public function download($path, $file) {
    file_put_contents($path, $file);
}
```

Though when I try to sync my local repository with the remote one with `git push` it says:

`Everything up-to-date`

What's the problem? `git pull` doesn't work either (`Already up-to-date.`)

Comment: Have you committed your changes locally?

Comment: @Chris How can I do that?

Comment: Depends on the tool you're using. On the command line, something like `git add the-file`, `git commit`. You say "I use GitHub to maintain my projects", but this is literally the most basic thing that Git does. Maybe you need to read a tutorial?

Comment: @Chris I'm using the command line. I haven't added a file so `git add` is useless.

Comment: No it's not. `git add` stages the file's changes. Again, please consider reading a Git tutorial.

Comment: @Chris OK. What should I use as argument then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by doing:

`git add .`

Then I did:

`git commit`

It opens your default editor and you should type the commit message, then save and close the editor. You will see something like:

```
Counting objects: 1, done.
Compressing objects: 100% (1/1), done.
Writing objects: 100% (1/1), 1 bytes, done.
Total 1 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0)
To client@server:user/repository.git
   9a4v59c..146v3qz  master -> master
```

Then I did `git pull` & `git push`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you haven't committed your changes locally.

1. Stage your modified file:

   ```
   git add path/to/the-file
   ```
2. Commit your changes locally:

   ```
   git commit
   ```
3. Push your changes to GitHub. Assuming your GitHub remote is called `origin`:

   ```
   git push origin master
   ```

You may want to consider reading a Git tutorial. Here are [Atlassian's tutorials](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorial) and here is [GitHub's interactive tutorial](https://try.github.io/levels/1/challenges/1).